# Problem with Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: cart, rules, shopping

I have a rule that has been working fine.  If a client orders more than $500 but less than $1000, they automatically receive a 5% discount.  I want to add a rule that says if they order more than $1000, they automatically receive a 10% discount.  I have tried the rule 6 times, and every time, it is applying the rule to the entire cart, even if the amount is $50.00.  I have double and triple checked the rule.  There are no conflicts with the first rule, and the conditions are written correctly.  I have re-indexed the site, and cleared the cache, after I implemented the new rule.  Not sure what to try next...assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried this one? http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Hope this helps!